# Clicking selector isn't triggering slide down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I'm implementing what I thought was just a simple slidedown of a secondary menu following this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XUwN5/1/

Here's my JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.selector').click(function () {
     $('#secondary-menu').slideToggle(300);
 });
});
```

HTML (to click this..):

```
<div id="secondary-menu">
[not included html because it's large]
</div>

<div class="selector">
Information
</div>
```

..should open the div '#secondary-menu'.

Forgot CSS, here it is:

```
#secondary-menu {
height: 40px;
background: #333;
position: relative;
z-index: 5000;
display: none;
}

.selector {
    position: absolute;
    padding:5px;
    left: 50%;
    /*border-radius: 10px;*/
    background-color: maroon;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 5000;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Here's the page for more info:
https://helloarchie.co/

It just doesn't slide down once the selector is clicked but not sure why the JS isn't working.

Comment: In your supplied HTML there is no #secondary-menu? So how can it toggle that div if it isn't there?

Comment: Are you sure you have included the script in your site`? because i cant find it anywhere.

Comment: @Granny There is if you look at the actual site, not jsfiddle

Comment: After looking again, i can confirm that you haven't included the code in your project.

Comment: Hmm, it was in the .js file which is definitely working because all the rest of the JS is working. I've now moved the script to the head to test and still not working.

Comment: Your code has to be after the jquery script (`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`)

Comment: You don't have jQuery included in your page. This is the error message you are getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @Zorken17 Yes jquery is included, the problem is that the code is loaded before jquery has been. all that needs to be done is move the script after jquery script

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I know, but that is the same as not included jQuery.

Comment: [Seems to be working...](https://jsfiddle.net/cLfet5t3/)

Comment: It seems to be working now